# Using zmq socket in a callback function

Tags: c++, zeromq

I have a callback function which will be called in a thread that I don't have any access or control to (a library created that thread, and requires me to exposure the callback function to that thread). Since a zmq socket is not thread safe, here is what I'm doing:

```
void callback () {
    zmq::socket_t tmp_sock(...); // create a socket which will be used only once
    ...
}
```

However, the callback is being invoked very frequently (hundreds of times per sec). Is there a better solution to use the socket more efficiently? I asked this because *The Guide* says: If you are opening and closing a lot of sockets, that's probably a sign that you need to redesign your application.

Edit:
Based on @raffian's answer. A `thread_local static` (available in C++11) variable in the callback function works fine.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I plan to use thread local storage to manage a socket. But I have no idea if it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question, but in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680096/pre-initializing-a-pool-of-worker-threads-to-reuse-connection-objects-sockets):

The principals are the same: pre-initialize a pool of worker threads, each with a dedicated socket, ready to use for reading/writing. In the Java example, I use `ThreadLocal`; I suppose in C++ you can use `#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>`. This approach is consistent with ZeroMq's guide; use sockets ***only*** in the threads that created them.

I'm not a C++ programmer, but if you use this approach, you'll have to do something like this:

```
void callback () {
    workerPool.doTask( new Task(args here));
    ...
}
```

Create a `Task`, with arguments, and send it to the workerPool, where it's assigned to a thread with dedicated socket. You'll want to create the worker pool with enough threads to accommodate load, nevertheless, concurrency shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `tss.hpp`. It sounds promising, I'll try to fit it in my program. +1

Comment: Here's a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6021676/642070) on how to dynamically init thread local storage in boost.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for providing the link. The `thread_local` keyword in C++11 also works