# Do thread_local variables need to be locked using a mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I considered `thread_local` variables as private variables for each thread, just with the same name. But all examples I found use a `mutex` variable to lock the `thread_local` variable when accessing it. This confused me. If `thread_local` is private for each thread, there is no need to take care of the concurrency problem, or my acknowledgement of the "private" idea is wrong?

Example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021273/how-to-allocate-thread-local-storage?lq=1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

thread_local unsigned int rage = 1; 
std::mutex cout_mutex;

void increase_rage(const std::string& thread_name)
{
    ++rage;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cout_mutex);
    std::cout << "Rage counter for " << thread_name << ": " << rage << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::thread a(increase_rage, "a"), b(increase_rage, "b");
    increase_rage("main");

    a.join();
    b.join();
}
```

In this case, is it necessary to lock the `thread_local` variable?

Comment: Which example? If you show it we might tell you why it uses a mutex, there might be a different reason for it.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl I got one:http://stackoverflow.com/a/15698197/2269707

Comment: The `mutex` there is only to synchronize the output through `std::cout` (`std::cout` isn't thread safe and could interleave the output) like the name suggests, it has nothing to do with the thread_local variables. You can see by the output that the thread_local variables are completely distinct.

Comment: The mutex also gets locked **AFTER** the `++rage`, the thread_local variable isn't protected at all and doesn't need to either.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl agree with you the mutex is for synchronizing `cout`

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl thanks so much. So can I get the conclusion that `thread_local` variables do not need to be synchronised?

Comment: Yes, `thread_local` variables don't need to be synchronized. The mutex was absolutely only necessary for the cout in your example.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl thanks, so helpful.

Comment: The explanation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983875/what-does-the-thread-local-mean-in-c11 should be very helpful in understanding what's going on here.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a pointer to a thread_local object, and pass the pointer to another thread, in some way, the other thread can still access the original thread's thread_local object using the pointer (until the originating thread terminates, after which point this becames undefined behavior).

So, if this can happen in your application, you will still need to arrange for mutex protection, or something equivalent, in order to access the thread_local object in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

Naming `thread_local` variables private variables is a bit unfortunate.

A `thread_local` declared variable is owned by its `thread` and not accessible by other `thread`s unless the owner `thread` (for some reason) gives them a pointer to that variable.
A `thread_local` variable is shared among all functions of its thread; i.e. it has its lifetime. If a `thread_local` variable is constructed it will be destroyed when its `thread` exits.

A `thread_local` variable can be static, in which case some care should be taken to make sure the program executes as expected. I won't go into this, since it is not part of the question.

The `mutex` in your example, as pointed out in the comments, is not for a data race condition. It is to synchronize the console output: the `mutex` is called `cout_mutex` - self explaining.